# impdp - ORA-39000: bad dump file specification

Tags: oracle

While importing a dump file using the command:

```
impdp manipur/manipur file=D:\ManipurCBSdump\MICB_TABLES.dmp full=yes log = implog.txt
```

The following error arises:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for impdp for Oracle 11 is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL908).  The FILE parameter that you have used should be DUMPFILE. Log should be LOGFILE.  Here is an example from the documentation

```
impdp hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp LOGFILE=dpump_dir2:expfull.log
```

Comment: Might be an idea to explain that `dpump_dir1` needs creating to point to `D:\ManipurCBSdump`

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have the directory created.

`select directory_name from dba_directories where directory_path = 'D:\ManipurCBSdump'`

If return rows, note the directory_name,  otherwise create the directory:

```
create directory imp_dir as 'D:\ManipurCBSdump'
```

Then execute the imp with the directory that was created or the one which existed in the first query:

```
impdp manipur/manipur file=MICB_TABLES.dmp directory=imp_dir full=yes log = implog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> impdp manipur/manipur file=D:\ManipurCBSdump\MICB_TABLES.dmp ...

The DataPump tools do not allow you to specify an arbitrary location for the dump and log files any more.

The location of these files are controlled by the Oracle DIRECTORY object that you use:

```
select 
  directory_name 
, directory_path 
from dba_directories 
order by 1 ; 

+----------------+-----------------------------------+
| DIRECTORY_NAME | DIRECTORY_PATH                    |
+----------------+-----------------------------------+
| DATA_PUMP_DIR  | ... default location ...          | 
| MICB_DIR       | D:\ManipurCBSdump\MICB_TABLES.dmp | 
+----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Then ...

```
impdp /@connection directory=MICB dumpfile=MICB_TABLES.dmp ...
      ^            ^              ^ 
      |            |              Dump file (name only) 
      |            Directory to be used for Dump and Log files 
      | 
      Read up on how to use Oracle Wallets to keep your credentials off the command-line.
```